# Using CHAR(13) in a FOR XML SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, for-xml

I'm trying to use CHAR(13) to force a new line, but the problem is, I'm doing this within a FOR XML Select statement:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) + Comment 
FROM 
   myTable 
FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '')
```

The problem with this, is that I don't get an actual new line.  Instead, I get:

```
#x0D;
```

So the data literally looks like this:

```
#x0D;First Line of Data#x0D;Second Line of Data#x0D;Etc
```

So I tried to just replace #x0D; with CHAR(13) outside of the FOR XML:

```
REPLACE(SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) + Comment 
FROM 
   myTable 
FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '')), '#x0D;', CHAR(13))
```

This gets me close.  It DOES add in the line breaks, but it also includes an & at the end of each line, and the start of each line after the first:

```
First Line of Data&
&Second Line of Data&
&Etc
```

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? Perhaps XML PATH isn't the PATH of least resistance.

Comment: Good point. Best way to answer that is to direct you to this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455033/merge-multiple-rows-of-same-column-into-a-single-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

The ultimate goal here was to present the data in Excel as part of a report.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but I at least got the results I wanted by doing this:

```
REPLACE (
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            (SELECT Comment FROM CallNotes WHERE ForeignId = a.ForeignId FOR XML PATH (''))
        , '<Comment>', '')  
    , '</Comment>', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
, '&#x0D;', '') AS Comments
```

The select statement all by itself returns XML as we would expect:

```
<comment>This is a comment</comment><comment>This is another comment</comment>
```

The inner most REPLACE just gets rid of the opening tag:

```
<comment>
```

The middle REPLACE removes the closing tag:

```
</comment>
```

and replaces it with CHAR(13) + CHAR(10).  And the outer most REPLACE gets rid of this:

```
&#x0D;
```

(I still don't understand where that's coming from.)

So, when the results are sent to Excel, it looks like this inside the cell:

```
This is a comment.
This is another comment.
```

Which is exactly what I want.  Again, I'm sure there is a better solution. But this at least is working for now.

Answer (score 12):

Your approach is not *real XML*:

Try this with "output to text":

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TestText VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('line 1'),('line 2'),('line 3');

SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT CHAR(10) + tbl.TestText
        FROM @tbl AS tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)
```

With `CHAR(13)`

```
#x0D;line 1&#x0D;line 2&#x0D;line 3
```

See that your `STUFF` just took away the ampersand?

With `CHAR(10)`

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

But what you really need is:

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT CHAR(10) + tbl.TestText --you might use 13 and 10 here
        FROM @tbl AS tbl
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''
)
```

The `,TYPE` will return *real XML* and with `.value()` you read this properly.

### Some background

You have a misconception of *"So the data literally looks like this"*

It does not *"look like this"*, it is escaped to fit to the rules **within** XML. And it will be back encoded implicitly, when you read it correctly.

And you have a misconception of line breaks:

In (almost) ancient times you needed a `CR = Carriage Return, 13 or x0D` to move back the printing sledge and additionally you needed a `LF = Line Feed, 10 or x0A` to turn the platen to move the paper. Hence the widely used need to have a line break coded with two characters (13/10 or 0D/0A).

Today the ASCII 10 (0A) is often seen alone...

But back to your actual problem: Why do you bother about the **look** of your data? Within XML some string might look ugly, but - **if you read this properly** - the decoding *back to the original look* is done implicitly...

Your *residues* are not more than part of the encoding as this starts with an ampersand and ends with a semicolon: `&lg`; or `&#x0D;`. Your attempt to replace this is just one character to short. But anyway: **You should not do this!**

Just try:

```
SELECT CAST('<x>&#x48;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is cleaner.  Basically start with line feeds (or some other special character) then replace them with carriage returns plus line feeds if you want.

```
Select REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT CHAR(10) + Comment 
                      FROM myTable FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, ''),
              CHAR(10), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose since you need to group on the FK you can use something like this... just replace #TempT with your table...

```
Select Pri.ForeignKey,
       Replace(Left(Pri.Notes,Len(Pri.Notes)-1),',',CHAR(13)) As Notes
From
    (
        Select distinct T2.ForeignKey, 
            (
                Select T1.Note + ',' AS [text()]
                From #TempT T1
                Where T1.ForeignKey = T2.ForeignKey
                ORDER BY T1.ForeignKey
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) Notes
        From #TempT T2
    ) Pri
```

Also in the OP that you listed in the comments, you have a duplicate PrimaryKey. I found that odd. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

If you use below query and results to text option you will see line breaks. Line breaks can't be shown using the results to grid functionality.

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT CHAR(10) + Comment 
FROM 
   myTable 
FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Comment + Char(10) + Char(13)

The "Carriage Return" "Line feed" should be at the end of the line.

Comment: Perhaps I am not fully sure the problem.  Xml is just a file.  An End of line in Windows is not the same as an end of line in Unix or Mac.  In Windows it is Carriage Return and Line Feed.  In Unix and Mac is is one of these two characters.  For windows you need both Char 10 and 13.  Not sure if it is 13 then 10 or 10 then 13.  For Mac or Unix you only use one.  Osx did it the Unix way older mac OS did it with the other character so even they are not the same.

Comment: This combination of `STUFF` and `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH` is a widely seen way to concatenate row data (like `group_concat` in MySQL). What many people miss (because this works in 99%) is, that this approach cannot deal with special characters... `CHAR(10)` would work, but `CHAR(13)` would not...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could help:

```
REPLACE(STUFF ((SELECT  CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + Field1 + Field2
    FROM
    ((table
    WHERE
    field3= 'condition1'
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '') , '&#x0D;' , '')
```